# Create XML node

Tags: xml, vb.net, treeview

I have the below XML file where I want to add a new child under first `<Profile_Path></Profile_Path>` node.

**Original XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profiles>
  <Profile>
    <Profile_Name>Profile 1</Profile_Name>
    <Profile_Path>E:\Test</Profile_Path>
  </Profile>
  <Profile>
    <Profile_Name>Profile 2</Profile_Name>
    <Profile_Path>E:\Test</Profile_Path>
  </Profile>
</Profiles>
```

**After running the code...**

```
Public Sub CreateProjectXml()

    ProfileList.Load(xml_path)
    Dim profilesNode As XmlNode = ProfileList.SelectSingleNode("Profiles")
    Dim profiles As XmlNodeList = profilesNode.SelectNodes("Profile")
    Dim profile As XmlNode = profiles(2)

    Dim project_info As XmlElement = ProfileList.CreateElement("Project_Name")

    project_info.InnerText = "Project 1"
    ProfileList.DocumentElement.AppendChild(project_info)

    ProfileList.Save(xml_path)

End Sub
```

**I get the following result:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Profiles>
      <Profile>
        <Profile_Name>Profile 1</Profile_Name>
        <Profile_Path>E:\Test</Profile_Path>
      </Profile>
      <Profile>
        <Profile_Name>Profile 2</Profile_Name>
        <Profile_Path>E:\Test</Profile_Path>
      </Profile>
      <Project_Name>Project 1</Project_Name>
    </Profiles>
```

Help me please with the correct code!

Comment: It would be helpful if you also gave an example of the desired output XML.  It's not entirely clear what you are attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you are appending the child by calling `ProfileList.DocumentElement.AppendChild`.  That method will append the child to the document element, which is the root-level `Profiles` element.  If you want to append the child to the first `Profile` element, you need to change it to this:

```
Public Sub CreateProjectXml()
    ProfileList.Load(xml_path)
    Dim profilesNode As XmlNode = ProfileList.SelectSingleNode("Profiles")
    Dim profiles As XmlNodeList = profilesNode.SelectNodes("Profile")
    Dim profile As XmlNode = profiles(0)
    Dim project_info As XmlElement = ProfileList.CreateElement("Project_Name")
    project_info.InnerText = "Project 1"
    profile.AppendChild(project_info)
    ProfileList.Save(xml_path)
End Sub
```

Notice in the above example, I changed it to use `profiles(0)` instead of `profiles(2)`, that way it will use the first one rather than the third one.

However, it is worth mentioning that `SelectNodes` and `SelectSingleNode` use XPath.  That means you can simplify your logic considerably by only selecting the one element you really want, for instance, if all you want is the very first `Profile` element, you could just do this:

```
Public Sub CreateProjectXml()
    ProfileList.Load(xml_path)
    Dim profile As XmlNode = ProfileList.SelectSingleNode("Profiles/Profile")
    Dim project_info As XmlElement = ProfileList.CreateElement("Project_Name")
    project_info.InnerText = "Project 1"
    profile.AppendChild(project_info)
    ProfileList.Save(xml_path)
End Sub
```

The `SelectSingleNode` method will only return the first matching element anyway, so you don't need to specify the index in the XPath, but if you want to be more explicit, you could specify the index to only get the first one, like this:

```
Dim profile As XmlNode = ProfileList.SelectSingleNode("Profiles/Profile[1]")
```

Or, if you wanted to get the third `Profile` element, you could use this XPath instead:

```
Dim profile As XmlNode = ProfileList.SelectSingleNode("Profiles/Profile[3]")
```

Or, if you wanted to get the `Profile` element which had a `Profile_Name` equal to "Profile 2", you could just do this:

```
Dim profile As XmlNode = ProfileList.SelectSingleNode("Profiles/Profile[Profile_Name='Profile 2']")
```

Etc.  If you are going to be working with XML much, it would be well worth your effort to spend some time learning the basics of XPath.  XPath is a standard XML query language which is used in many XML tools and programming languages.  For instance, if you are going to ever use XSLT, you'll need to understand XPath.  XPath can be used with the `XmlDocument` class, as I mentioned above, and also with the newer `XDocument` class.

The alternative to XPath is to use LINQ.  LINQ is a proprietary Microsoft technology, so you won't find any support for it in other tools and languages outside of .NET, but many people do prefer it.  The new `XDocument` class is designed to make XML easy to work with via LINQ.  Combined with VB.NET's support for inline XML literals, this task is actually quite easy with `XDocument`:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xml_path)
doc.<Profiles>.<Profile>(0).Add(<Project_Name>Project 1</Project_Name>)
doc.Save(xml_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex I think you shoud use the following code

```
ProfileList.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(project_info, profiles.FirstChild)
```

Insted of

```
ProfileList.DocumentElement.AppendChild(project_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using VB.Net, you can work with XML the easy way.

```
Dim xml = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <Profiles>
                <Profile>
                    <Profile_Name>Profile 1</Profile_Name>
                    <Profile_Path>E:\Test</Profile_Path>
                </Profile>
                <Profile>
                    <Profile_Name>Profile 2</Profile_Name>
                    <Profile_Path>E:\Test</Profile_Path>
                </Profile>
            </Profiles>

xml...<Profile>.First().Add(<Project_Name>Project 1</Project_Name>)
```

Now `xml` is

```
<Profiles>
  <Profile>
    <Profile_Name>Profile 1</Profile_Name>
    <Profile_Path>E:\Test</Profile_Path>
    <Project_Name>Project 1</Project_Name>
  </Profile>
  <Profile>
    <Profile_Name>Profile 2</Profile_Name>
    <Profile_Path>E:\Test</Profile_Path>
  </Profile>
</Profiles>
```

so you basically just need this:

```
Public Sub CreateProjectXml()
    ProfileList.Load(xml_path)
    ProfileList...<Profile>.First().Add(<Project_Name>Project 1</Project_Name>)
    ProfileList.Save(xml_path)
End Sub
```